# Convert columns of states and college towns in Pandas into two columns, Column 1: States and Columns 2: Associated College Towns

Tags: pandas

I have a series in Pandas which is a column of states, and underneath each state, the college towns in that state.

E.g.

**New York**:
Ithaca
New York City
**North Carolina**
Durham
Raleigh
etc...

This is all in one column descending in alphabetical order of state.

I have to separate this data, by creating a new column to the left which will be the list of states, and associated college towns to the right. e.g.

Column 1: New York / Column 2: Ithaca

Aside from manually typing out a dictionary for each state to associate college towns, is there an elegant way to form these associations and create the two column structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your sample data (properly formatted) is:

```
0          New York
1            Ithaca
2     New York City
3    North Carolina
4            Durham
5           Raleigh
dtype: object
```

Each "sector" (concerning particular state) starts from the state name
and then there is a number of cells with cities - university sites.

Start from creating of an auxiliary *Series* containing only state names.
For your sample data, limited to just 2 states, it can be:

```
states = pd.Series(['New York', 'North Carolina'])
```

Of course, in the target implementation include here **all** state names.

Then, to generate the result, run:

```
result = s.groupby(s.isin(states).cumsum()).apply(
    lambda grp: pd.DataFrame({'State': grp.iloc[0], 'City': grp.iloc[1:]}))\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

For your sample data, the result is:

```
            State           City
0        New York         Ithaca
1        New York  New York City
2  North Carolina         Durham
3  North Carolina        Raleigh
```

Comment: Thanks, the data is formatted that way! I was not sure how to configure the dataframe in the answer as you did, hence my resorting to a crude description.